# Выводит [object Object] при получении значения из массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

Когда я пытаюсь достать значение из массива, мы выводит [object Object]

Код:

```
$.getJSON("../json/" + str + ".json", function(data) {
  var vname = data.vname;
  var src = data.src;
  var desc = data.desc;
  var date = data.date;
  var comments = data.comments; //"проблемный" массив
  var cmt = comments[i]; //i == 2
  alert("cmt= " + cmt); //это выводит [object Object]
  var tcmt = cmt[0];
  alert("tcmt= " + tcmt);
  var idpcmt = (_.invert(hash))[tcmt];
  alert("idpcmt= " + idpcmt);
});
```

Вот и сама запись массива в json:

```
"comments":{"1":{"-1":"1"},"2":{"-2":"2"},"3":{"11":"Jsjdjsj"},"4":{"11":"Jsjdjsjhgfd"}}
```

Comment: А где тут у вас массив? Вижу объект состоящий из объектов. Попробуйте alert(JSON.stringify(data.comments["1"])) и получите первый объект.

Comment: Damon Haswell, попробовал, в ответ все тот же [object Object]

Comment: Выводит первый элемент объекта https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/561117/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде было неявное преобразование из объекта в строку, что и даёт  результат в виде `[object Object]`. Используйте `JSON.stringify()` для явного преобразования объекта в строку json формата.

```
$.getJSON("../json/" + str + ".json", function(data) {
  var vname = data.vname;
  var src = data.src;
  var desc = data.desc;
  var date = data.date;
  var comments = data.comments; //"проблемный" массив
  var cmt = comments[i]; //i == 2
  alert("cmt= " + JSON.stringify(cmt)); //теперь это будет выводить объект в строковом json формате
  var tcmt = cmt[0];
  alert("tcmt= " + tcmt);
  var idpcmt = (_.invert(hash))[tcmt];
  alert("idpcmt= " + idpcmt);
});
```